# Questions about the principle of routes matching in Kong

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I have some problems when using Kong to configure routing .I need to apply the login authentication plug-in to the specified api path.

For example,

- If there is a Route named ‘Route1’ and it’s path is '`/api/phone`',
- I want to apply the authentication plug-in to all requests under the path of '`/api/phone/sell`'.
  So I built a Route named ‘Route2’ with path:'`/api/phone/sell`'.

But when I actually called it, it was different from what I expected.

When my request path is '`/api/phone/sell`', the matched Route is ‘Route1’. Only when my request path is '`/api/phone/sell/abc`' can I match ‘Route2’.

This has caused me confusion, because I recently upgraded my version of kong from 0.14.x to 1.3.x, and there was no such problem in the previous version. Is it because I don’t understand the path matching principle correctly, or is there some adjustments in Kong after a certain version?

All help appreciated!

Comment: I know that you can match all requests under the sell path by writing the regular expression `/api/phone/sell[\s\S]*$`, but shouldn’t this be the kong default operation?